# BMT in client-side classes?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions

I have a 3-layer application with a client-container, EJB-container (business-layer and data-access-layer). I want to make transactions in my client by using BMT. My EJBs on the EJB-container are all working with CMT.

But I am not sure if that actually works, since the client is not working in an EJB-container. The client injects the EJBs of the EJB-container with lookups on a Context object, which seem to work fine. I declared my client-side class as:

```
@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
```

Is this correct? I guess the client side class which is used by my GUI has to be a singleton.

I have these objects:

```
private Context jndiCntx;
private UserTransaction tx;

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() throws Exception {
    jndiCntx = new InitialContext();
    tx = (UserTransaction) jndiCntx.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    tx.begin();
}
```

And this PostConstruct initializes the transaction. 
Here is where I get a NullPointerException (in commitOrder()):

```
@Override
public void commitOrder() throws ApplicationException {
    try {
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ApplicationException("", "commitOrder() failed!");
    }
}

@Override
public void cancelOrder() throws ApplicationException {
    try {
        tx.rollback();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ApplicationException("", "cancelorder() failed!");
    }
}
```

So it seems like that I don't get a UserTransaction object. I am slightly confused by the different ways of using contexts and transactions. What am I doing wrong? And by the way: What is the difference between using a Transaction with a TransactionManager and using a UserTransaction?

Comment: Is your client a standalone application?

Comment: No, I have a client project in netbeans, and an enterprise application project

Comment: You need to find out if your application server supports transactions from "application clients". This is optional according to the Java EE 7 spec. If they are supported then you also need to find out the correct procedure for packaging your application client so that the EE support is built in. Client side EJB implementations (such as your @Singleton above) are *not* supported.

Comment: I am using GlassFish and Java EE 6. How can I check if my application server supports transactions from "application clients"?

Comment: If client side EJB implementations are not supported, how can I do BMT in my client-project?